Request blocked by CORS policy when trying to fetch image
I'm developing a web app where the user can create projects and upload up to 5 images for each project. I'm using PHP for the API and the following code for configuring CORS inside my index.php:
// Specify domains from which requests are allowed
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

// Specify which request methods are allowed
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');

// Additional headers which may be sent along with the CORS request
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With,Authorization,Content-Type');

// Set the age to 1 day to improve speed/caching.
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');

// Exit early so the page isn't fully loaded for options requests
if (strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'options') {
    exit();
}

I'm storing the uploaded images in the public/img directory and running the PHP server with php -S localhost:3000 -t public/.
For all configured routes I'm returning a JSON response, for instance:
// GET|/project/details
// controller class (implements Psr\Http\Server\RequestHandlerInterface)
  $project = $this->repository->find($id);
  $dto = new ProjectDetailsDto($project);

  return new Nyholm\Psr7\Response(200, ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],json_encode($dto));

In the web app I'm receiving the JSON responses correctly; I'm displaying the images in the HTML with <img src="http://localhost:3000/img/image.jpg"> with no problems; also, if access http://localhost:3000/img/image.jpg in the browser or with a Postman GET request, i get the image with no problems.
The problem is i need to fetch the image with Javascript; I'm using the following code:
const image = await fetch(BASE_URL + imagePath); // http://localhost:3000/img/image.jpg
const imageBlob= await image.blob();

This is triggering the following error:
project.html:1 Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3000/img/image.jpg' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
When I'm accessing the image the request doesn't seem to be going through the index.php. I need help to figure out why the CORS error is occurring and how to fix it.
Link for the repository, if further code is needed: Repository.

Just for context: I've started learning PHP about 3 weeks ago because i need to develop a project for a class.
I'm actually "migrating" this API from a Node.js project I've done last year so that i can reuse the front-end and focus on PHP.

When I'm accessing the image the request doesn't seem to be going through the index.php...correct. Your webserver can serve an image natively, it doesn't need PHP for that!

i need to fetch the image with Javascript...why, what are you going to do with it after that?

Anyway I doubt you can add CORS headers into the PHP basic webserver. You probably need to run the PHP side code off something like Apache, so you can set a rule in the .htaccess file (that's a configuration file you can put in a folder, which Apache will use when processing requests) which would add suitable CORS headers to responses for other file types such as images.

Also...in case you hadn't realised you're getting a CORS error in the first place because you seem to be running the frontend on a different hostname and port than the backend, and then trying to request a resource from the server via AJAX/fetch - that's the only scenario in which CORS restrictions are applied.  It's not a problem to host the frontend and backend separately - it's a reasonably common scenario in web app architecture, but it does introduce that extra complication of CORS.

...why, what are you going to do with it after that?
I was going to place it inside the input in the form for when the user wants to edit the project. Right now I'm thinking that there are a lot of simpler and better ways of doing that... The edit form receives all the data from the project, including the images, and when it's submitted all the images are re-submitted...

Anyway I doubt you can add CORS headers into the PHP basic webserver... I think this actually solves the question and I need to come up with a better logic for my edit form.

I was going to place it inside the input in the form...you can't do that anyway. An <input type="file" can't be modified. It can only be used to select images from the user's disk. You can't put images into it. And anyway what would be the point? The image is already uploaded, so why upload it again? If you want to show what the existing uploaded image is, for reference, then simply make a regular <img tag to display it. Then the user can choose to upload a new one, or just leave it blank. Your PHP code should not attempt to delete the existing image unless a new one is uploaded.

@ADyson I was doing it using a DataTransfer object and placing it inside input.files; the point (it's bad, I realize it now) was that input was presented for the user with the image inside and he could let it as it was, remove it or replace it. Your comments cleared out to me the problem I was having with CORS and that the webserver can serve an image natively. Also, I've realized that I'm gonna have to review and update my old web app code because some of the logic isn't good.

"When I'm accessing the image the request doesn't seem to be going through the index.php" - you could achieve that, if you started the server with a router script, see Example #5 Handling Unsupported File Types. Only then your script is responsible for serving all static assets, which means you have to include logic to respond with the correct Content-Type header at least. [...]

[...] But all in all, I wouldn't recommend this - the built-in web server is far from what you will eventually use to actually host your application when it goes "live", and such significant differences between your development system and the eventual target system, can introduce a lot of additional troubles. Setting up a local web server (Apache/WAMP/LAMP), is usually the better choice.
